# Writing a to a text file using asp script - web form

Tags: asp.net, forms, jsp

I am trying to write into a text file using an asp script but i am having an **405 Not Allowed** allowed error on the cloud server and i was display a copy of my asp code when i tried to run it on my local server xampp. I am not really sure why this is the case.

Would be glad to accept any form of help and comments.

THanks

I have 2 files.
**Test.jsp**

```
<form action="neww.asp" method="post" >
Name: <input type = "text" name="name"><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**neww.asp**

```
<%
    Dim fso, f, filespec
    dim name
    name=Request.QueryString("name")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    filespec = Server.Mappath("C:/User/user/Desktop/putty1.txt")

    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filespec,2)

    ' Write a text line

    f.WriteLine (name)


    %>
```

Comment: Why are you using OLD asp rather than asp.net? These days you can code it all with "code behind" in Visual Studio with intellisense and all, and using any language that Visual Studio supports, and then deploy the build as a DLL.

Answer (score 2):

The 405 error means the method you're trying to use is not supported by the page.

The problem is here:

```
name=Request.QueryString("name")
```

Request.QueryString only supports GET.  But in your form you've defined the method as POST.

To use POST, you should be doing:

```
name=Request.Form("name")
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. Doesnt seems to work in my case.